# Simple twisting riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay

One of the riddles we used to have painted on the walls of one of our classrooms in secondary school (with the last part added in :+ ):

> What runs but doesn't walk,
>   has a mouth yet still can't talk,
>   has a head but doesn't think,
>   has a bed but will not sleep
>   and twists yet is not a riddle?

Took us 12 year old students a couple of days to figure out back then (despite it being terribly obvious in hindsight of course). So just wondering how many minutes it will take here :P .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is

> A river. As you said, it is pretty obvious. They run, have heads, mouths, and beds, and they often twist.

Comment: I think you are the one who answered first.

Comment: @AeJey I did. I edited mine 53 minutes ago, he answered 52 minutes ago. I don't see why his is accepted over mine.

Comment: Yes. I have noticed that too. May be a mistake by the OP. Hope he will correct it after seeing our conversation.

Answer (score 10):

Is it a

> river?

Because

> A river runs, there is a river mouth, a river head, a riverbed, and there are rivers with twisting shapes.

Comment: In our geography room indeed :D It was so obvious afterwards :P

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! I was hesitant to answer that at first, rarely schools have the real one in hindsight!

Answer (score 4):

Anyone with

> young toddlers

knows that they:

- tend to run instead of walk
- have a mouth but don't talk
- certainly have a head but don't think all that well
- don't use their bed to sleep
- will twist if you try to hold them

Comment: (+1): ha! I never thought of this! xD