# Always A-head of the game

Tags: riddle

A super fun riddle here:

> It has a head but never cries
>   It has a bed but never sleeps in it
>   It can run but never can it walk
>   It has a bank with money

What is this riddle describing?

Comment: Very similar to this: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5677/simple-twisting-riddle and the same answer, I would guess.

Comment: @hexomino but then it would be a bank *without* money (I guess).

Comment: (Xilpex, I just saved your puzzle from the duplicate pit, all you have to do is make up an answer that will fit well with your typo ;) )

Comment: the dupli-pit, huh?

Comment: Just fell in to the dupli-pit. Its so muddy. I'm now dirty. :D

Comment: @Xilpex so, in seriousness, is this the same as the linked riddle?

Comment: @Brandon_J Just about...

Comment: In that case, it's probably going to get closed as a dupe. You have clever phrasing, but it's still very similar, as hexomino pointed out.